# Single drop-down list that draws its data from 2 different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m new to SQL so please forgive. I’m using phpMyAdmin v3.4 and MySQL (server version) v5.5.
Is it possible please to provide a patient with a single drop-down list that draws its data from 2 different columns? As follows:

Table: PRACTICE

```
SurgeryID | Doctor | Assistant

1_______________| Atkin__| Cashmore

2_______________| Obrien | Morgan

3_______________| Heron_  | Chapman

Table: BOOKING

BookingID | PatientName | DocOrAss

10001___  | Spock___________ | Atkin (DropDownListOffered)

10002__________| Scotty_____________  |  Morgan (DropDownListOffered)

10003__________|  Kirk_______________|    Heron (DropDownListOffered)
```

The patient belongs to just one particular Surgery (SurgeryID which is the PK) and must be able to select (from the drop down list) either the Doctor (unique), or, the Doctors Assistant (unique) but not both from just that one Surgery i.e. the patient should not be able to see the other Doctors and Assistant who are at other Surgery’s .  I'm aware that it would be perhaps more usual to structure the table such that the Doctor and Assistant were in the same column but I'd like to understand if it is possible to look to 2 different columns as though they are one.

I'd like to implement this simply, as a permanent table perhaps through some kind of composite key rather than manipulating in code. If this is not possible e.g. perhaps no function to help do this and or the table structure is considered as poor design, then I'll move on - any suggestions on redesign are welcome.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do can be done using SQL similar to below which unions the table with itself and assigns the same alias to the 2 different columns.

```
select
    doctor as DocOrAss
from
    practice
where
    surgeryid = 1
union
select
    assistant as DocOrAss
from
    practice
where
    surgeryid = 1
```

Result should be similar to

```
DocOrAss
--------
Atkin
Cashmore
```

However the design doesn't feel quite right.

An issue you may run into might be when you select a DocOrAss how do you know if they are a doctor or an assistant?  Also how can you easily find out which surgery they come from?

The problem with the design of the practise table is that your table seems to have 3 responsibilities

1. listing doctors
2. listing surgery's
3. listing Assistants

This is a bit much for one table and breaks the [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) principle if a surgery can have more than one doctor.  It probably would be good to break that up a bit, maybe even into 3 tables.

Or if all you are trying to do is list all the doctors in a particular surgery (assuming assistants are really just other doctors) then perhaps a better but still simple design might be to create a table called Doctors (DoctorId[Pk], Name, SurgeryId).  Then you can do a select for all doctors from a particular surgeryId.